# Get Error from calling template object in script tag (google web app)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I try to pass template object to both html and javascript
but I got error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at"
from javascript tag

I did reseach from forum and many code suggest to use JSON.stringify and JSON.phase
but still got same error

PS. Right Now, I just using param to pass variable to javascript
but i'm not sure ,this is a proper way to do

Code.gs

```
    function doPost(e) {

    if(e.parameter.LoginButton == 'Login' || typeof(e.parameter.userQR) == "string"){    

    var  usercode  =  e.parameter.usercode;
    var  password  = e.parameter.password ;
    var  Userdata
    
    if(typeof(usercode) == "string"){
         Userdata = checkLogin(usercode, password); // 
    }else{
         Userdata = checkLoginByQR(e.parameter.userQR)
    
    }

    if(Userdata != 'FALSE'){     ////// Login Success

            return render('Menu',{'usercode':Userdata.ID,'username':Userdata.Username,'division':Userdata.Division,'level':Userdata.Level,message:"",access:LevelToArray(Userdata.Level)})

          };
}

    function render(file,argsObject){
    
    var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
    if(argsObject){
      var keys = Object.keys(argsObject) ;
    
          keys.forEach(function(key){
      
              tmp[key] = argsObject[key] ;
    
            });
    
          } // END IF
       return    tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) ;
    }
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?!= include('Main-Resource'); ?>
      <?!= include('Main-CSS'); ?> <!-- See Main-CSS file --> 

    <style type="text/css">
      

  body.th :lang(my),option.th :lang(my) {
                    display: none;
                    }
  body.my :lang(th),option.my :lang(th) {
                    display: none;
                    }

</style>    

  </head>
    <body>
    <section class="ftco-section">
        <div class="container-fluid px-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center mb-8">
                    <h1 class="heading-section">ระบบข้อมูลพนักงาน </h1><br>

         <span class="badge text-bg-light row justify-content-center"><?= access[1]; ?></span><br>    

          <div class="alert alert-primary row justify-content-center" lang="th">
                USER: <?= usercode; ?> <?= username; ?>  DIVISION: <?= division; ?>    Level: <?= access[0]; ?> 
                </div>


                <param id="loginuser" value="<?= usercode; ?> <?= username; ?>">
                <param id="LevelName" value="<?= access[0]; ?>">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="login-wrap p-4 p-md-4">
               
              <param id="Response" value="<?=message ;?>">
              <div id="MenuAlert"></div> 

            <br>

            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

  <?!= include('Main-JS'); ?> 
  <?!= include('Menu-JS'); ?> 
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
...
var desiredValue = <?!= usercode ?>;
console.log(desiredValue)
...// Want to get usercode value to do next stuff .... Please help!
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide complete html.  I cannot reproduce your results.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it this way and it works fine.

```
function render(file, argsObject) {
  const tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
  if (argsObject) {
    let keys = Object.keys(argsObject);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      tmp[key] = argsObject[key];
    });
  }
  Logger.log(tmp.evaluate().getContent());
  const theend = "isnear"
}

function intmed() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  render ('ah1',{lfunko:vs});
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = lfunko ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you , Cooper . but stil not quire understand your suggestion .
my console always show ,That error when I type sciptlet syntax inside <script> tag